# Changing inherited class name in XML C#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xsd

I am serializing a set of classes that looks like:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    IInterface obj;
}

public interface IInterface 
{
}

[XmlType("ClassA")]
public ImplA : IInterface 
{
}
```

Currently the XML generated looks like

```
<Wrapper>
   <IInterface xsi:type="ClassA">
...
   </IInterface>
</Wrapper>
```

Is there anyway to include the custom type name as the element name, instead of including it in the type?

Comment: I suspect the answer is to write your own serializer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it for this tree, you can put the XmlElementAttribute declaration in your wrapper:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="ClassA")]
    IInterface obj;
}
```

Comment: This will use the element name ClassA for any implementation of IInterface. I believe the OP is looking for something that will only use ClassA as an element name for the class ImplA.

Comment: That's right, there would be multiple implementation for the interface.

Comment: @codechobo - But would you want each implementation to have the same element name or each implementation have a different element name (this would give them all the same element name).

Comment: Different element names, so I think the names would have to be defined within the inherited classes

Comment: @Justin Niessner Ah, I see what you're saying.  Yes, this would make the element named "ClassA" for all implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the XmlIncludeAttribute:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    //XmlInclude should in this case at least include ImplA, but you propably want all other subclasses/implementations of IInterface
    [XmlInclude(typeof(ImplA)), XmlInclude(typeof(ImplB))]
    IInterface obj;
}
```

This makes the xml serializer aware of the subtypes of IInterface, which the property could hold.